# pymongo collection object serializing __getnewargs__ method

Tags: python, serialization, celery, pymongo, pickle

Pymongo collection object fails when i try to run my tasks with celery. I guess it couldn't serialize it. What should i do? By the way i tried pickle but it doesn't help me.

PS: I don't want to make global db import to this module.

'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the '**getnewargs**' method....

Sample code is below.
**module.py**

```
from celery.contrib.methods import task_method



class Some_Class(object):
    """docstring for Some_Class"""
    def __init__(self, db):
        super(Some_Class, self).__init__()
        self.db = db  # This object causes 'Collection' object is not callable
        #db is a pymongo collection object from db.py


    @app.task(filter=task_method)  # Celery task
    def add(self):
        """
        db.insert({'some_key':'some_value'})
        """
        return 3
```

**db.py**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient    
db = MongoClient()['test']['collection']
```

Comment: If you are looking to inspect what leads to failure in the serializability of objects, you can try methods in the `dill.detect` module. https://github.com/uqfoundation

Comment: Are you running this code on a Windows machine? There might be an underlying fork issue since 'fork' doesn't exist on Windows, so the object might not be pickable which causes an error.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be serializing collection objects. Instead store collection *name* and obtain collection object from within the task.

Collection objects require the associated established MongoClient object graph to be usable. Without the MongoClient, even if you somehow managed to deserialize a collection object, it wouldn't work.